# How to get LifecycleOwner in WearableActivity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I am facing a problem when I try to use LiveData from WearableActivity:

```
val livedata = ...
val observer = ...
livedata.observe(this, observer)
```

It worked when I was working with activity extending AppCompatActivity but it looks like WearableActivity does not implement LifecycleOwner interface, altough it does own a lifecycle, right? (observe method requires LifecycleOwner as the first argument). How can I make it work?

Comment: I would speculate that in case WearableActivity doesn't implement LifecycleOwner, then you would need to do so in your code and override the getLifeCycle() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest approach as shown on the official [Android sample projects](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/master/AlwaysOn/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/alwayson/MainActivity.java) is to extend `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` and implement `AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // setContentView will be the same as before
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Initialize yourCustomObserver here or have it injected

    // FragmentActivity has getLifeCycle() so you get it for free
    getLifeCycle().addObserver(yourCustomObserver);
}
```

That's it, and you won't need to manually update your LifecycleOwner (aka Activity) lifecycle state.

#### Previous Answer

Further to the previous comment by Karan Modi, you may implement your own `getLifeCycle()` according to the guide in the lifecycle documentation.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#implementing-lco

Specifically, you may implement your own LifeCycleOwner as shown:

```
public class MyActivity extends WearableActivity implements LifecycleOwner {
    private LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.